# Using Intents to navigate between activities

Tags: android, android-intent

### I usually navigate between the Activities using *`Intents`*

***Pictorial representation looks as below::***

[image]

**In Activity - A .......... There is a next button to go to activity B**

```
Photos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent PhotoIntent=new Intent(a.this,b.class);
                startActivity(PhotoIntent);

            }
        });
```

**In Activity - B .......... There is a next button to go to again activity C**

```
Map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent PhotoIntent=new Intent(b.this,c.class);
                    startActivity(PhotoIntent);

                }
            });
```

- Now in Activity C .... there is only one back button
- If I use it i similarly to above code I can't go to two activities
  depending on the navigation i came from

Suppose i came from `A` to `C` ------ when i use `Back` button in `C` go to `A`

Again when came from `B` to `C` ----- when i use `Back` button in `C` go to `B`

There is only one `back` `button` in Activity `C`

---

**[Edit]**

Its like Say i came from `Activity` A to `Activity C` ----- When i USE the only back button in `Activity C` it should go to `activity A`

&

For the same scenario if i came from Activity B to Activity C - - - - When i USE the only back button in `Activity C` it should go to `activity B`

------- **I am trying to relate a switching case kind of mechanism for Back button in ActivityC**

---

How to Achieve this

Hope i am clear

Comment: You didn't say what you want to do, only what it does now.

Comment: Achieve what? Your question is not clear!

Comment: @ Tenfour04 & @  Lazy Ninja .......Please Check the Updated question ... i have added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There is only one back button in Activity C
```

If I understand correctly, `Activity C` can be started from both `Activity A` and `Activity B`. If this is the case, the back button in Activity C should have the following code:

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Takes you to whichever activity launched C
        finish();
    }
});
```

When you launch Activity C from Activity A, the stack is .... {Activity A}, {Activity C}. Calling `Activity#finish()` in Activity C will take you to Activity A. Same scenario unfolds when Activity C is started from Activity B.

Note that if you call finish() in Activity A after launching Activity C, the back button will take you to the Activity that is positioned before Activity A in the stack.

Comment: Perfect Answer ! ...... And a clear explanation also .... Your explanation of mechanism of stack functioning improved my understanding of navigation in android .... Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                onBackPressed();

            }
        });
```

In this way , you have called back button functionality of device Now the OS will decide where to navigate according to the Stack, whether Activity A is present or Activity B in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

call finish() or onBackPressed() function on back button click event.